# ElasticSearch Query_String regex false positives

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I'm running this query in elastic search and not getting all of the correct answers but also false positives.

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "/(function|sub) FormSubmit/i",
      "fields": [
        "fileContents"
      ]
    }
```

Can anyone explain why this would be happening?

Comment: Can you please include some of the words you are looking through, what you would like to match and what you do not want to match.

Comment: I'm looking through entire files. I'd like to match things like: `function formsubmit` or `sub formsubmit` case insensitive

Comment: What I meant was for you to post some sort of sample data, which should include values you want to match, values which you do not want to match and also values which yield potential false positives.

Comment: Well what i'm searching against isn't something i can post here and a mockup would just be the same as what i said in the comments.

Comment: Not even the false positives?

Comment: Have you tried doing a phrase search?  e.g. set your query string to `"function formsubmit" or "sub formsubmit"`

Comment: @OllyCruickshank That would work for simple regex...but I want the user to be able to input any regex they want...and parsing that into phrase searches would be an enormous amount of work. I just don't understand why the documentation says you can use regex and it doesn't seem to work. npinti They are files from my company...even the false positives.